# What is this bush/tree that has dark leaves, and clusters of tiny white flowers with 4 petals?

Tags: identification, trees, shrubs

There is this bush where I live, in Florida, US. It's taller than 5 feet, maybe 5'5. It has really tiny (less than half an inch) white flowers with 4 petals. The flowers are not fragrant. It's been there for over 10 years and we're trying to identify what it is.

The first picture is a fresh cut, so it is in flower now. Below that are more pictures of a larger area, including flowers.

[image: closeup]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: My first impulse is to say it's a Holly (of the genus ilex) but I don't have the energy to check RN.

Comment: Grateful enough to provide a general location of where this plant was found?

Comment: I think @PatrickZissou is right (because of the flowers). But photo is not so good. And for tree, also a photo of entire tree helps.

Comment: The photo's too dark, can you post another one preferably taken in bright daylight please, as well as saying where you are - is this a fresh branch you've cut (meaning its in flower now?) Are the flowers fragrant?

Comment: Sorry for not giving all the info at once, I'm not really good with gardening. I'm currently in Florida, US. The flowers are not fragant. Here are a few pictures of the tree: [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/332053117795303425/423497016061198337/DSC_0342.jpg) [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/332053117795303425/423497016732155904/DSC_0341.jpg) [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/332053117795303425/423497017352781824/DSC_0343.jpg) [link](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/332053117795303425/423497015612145664/IMG-20180314-WA0000.jpg)

Comment: Welcome marta! Thanks for this great first question! You'll see it looks a bit different now. I edited the title to add details, brought the pictures in from your links, and added in the information you gave as answers to questions in comments. Since our system is different from others, I invite you to visit our [help]. It will guide you through how we do things and why. If you have any questions about that, please leave a comment here and someone, like the people who are already helping you, will respond! Have fun here!

Comment: By the way, those pictures are gorgeous, and we appreciate that you sized them in such an excellent manner! They look very symmetrical!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good lead from @Patrick Zissou. The O.P. @Marta does not mention a location where this is growing, but my guess is *[Ilex vomitoria](http://www.sbs.utexas.edu/bio406d/images/pics/aqu/ilex_vomitoria.htm)*, Yaupon Holly.

Edit: thanks to Marta for the additional images and info. I still think Ilex vomitoria is a good match and is native to Florida.

http://www.fnps.org/plants/plant/ilex-vomitoria

Answer (score 1):

What about Rhaphiolepis?

Rhaphiolepis is a genus of about fifteen species of evergreen shrubs and small trees in the family Rosaceae, native to warm temperate and subtropical eastern and southeastern Asia, from southern Japan, southern Korea and southern China south to Thailand and Vietnam.

Originally I suspected Rhaphiolepis indica (Indian hawthorn), however this species produces pink flowers. After a little research I suspected Rhaphiolepis umbellata (Yeddo hawthorn) which produces white flowers, however they are scented.

I did find reference to a white flowering Rhaphiolepis indica - [Rhaphiolepis Cosmic White](http://www.australianplantsonline.com.au/rhaphiolepis-indica-cosmic-white.html) - however the flowers appear to be too large.

I note @Marta (OP) confirms her location is Florida USA. Rhaphiolepis indica is popular in subtropical and tropical regions in Australia and I also read on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhaphiolepis) that...

> Indian Hawthorn is a mainstay horticultural specimen in southern
>   United States. It is often found in commercial as well as in private
>   landscapes.

Maybe @Marta (OP) could confirm whether the plant produces any fruit? I note that Rhaphiolepis sp. produce small fruit 1-2 cm (0.39–0.79 in) diameter and coloured dark purple to black.

Comment: Rhaphiolepis should have 5-merous flowers with the ovary inferior. The plant posted here shows 4-merous flowers with superior ovary position.